# pose position to reset position?

Tags: animation, rigging

[image]

I've already cleared all user rotation, and also tried alt R etc... when I press the reset position button ever thing looks good, but in pose position is pressed the head legs and arms twist in a funny direction how do I fix this without redoing everything?

please I need help  thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6):

1. In pose mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all bones
2. Click the *Pose* menu (in the header, next to *Select*).
3. Under *Apply*, click *Apply Pose at Rest Pose*.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you reset the rotation in the pose mode? Because i assume you reset the rotation for the armature rotation as object in object mode, while you are supposed to reset every bone rotation inside the pose mode.

If this is the case, enter *Pose Mode* for your armature, select all bones by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then reset the rotation by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to reset location if necessary.